# JS: electron use fs.readSync in render process

Tags: javascript, electron, fs

use `fs.readSync()` in render process,and element of buffer is always 0.
use `fs.read()` will get correct result.

```js
const electron = window.require('electron');
const { remote } = electron;
const fs = remote.require('fs');

const fd = fs.openSync(localPath, 'r');
const fileStat = fs.fstatSync(fd);

const { size: fileSize } = fileStat;
const dataBuffer = Buffer.alloc(fileSize);
const readSize = 1024;
for(let i = 0; i < fileSize; i += readSize) {
  fs.readSync(fd, dataBuffer, i, Math.min(fileSize - i, readSize), null);
  console.log(dataBuffer);
}
```

Comment: For `fs` you don't need to require it via electron remote (as it's default nodejs module). Write `const fs = require('fs')` simply. I don't know why it's not working the other way though.

Comment: if use `const fs = require('fs')` directly in render process, throw error `fs.openSync is not a function`.Maybe it is because array is copied through remote ? Is there anyway to load a large file?

Answer (score 0):

Return `0` probably means that the synchronized operation is failed with `remote`. You might capture exception in main thread.

*BTW: Synchronized function call will be very slow in nodejs. That's why all these functions are named with `Sync` as suffix. I'd high recommend you write async code everywhere if it is possible.*

Comment: Maybe it is because array is copied through remote ? Is there anyway to load a large file? Transfer data from main process to render process is too slow.

Comment: I don't exactly know why you want to load large local file into a browser window (render process). Here are some thoughts: (1) you can use native html5 file api to load file like any file uploader in browser (2) you can register your own secure protocol between main and render processes (like this https://github.com/stanleyxu2005/electron-utils/blob/master/lib/protocol.js) and then you can load contents at the fastest speed

Comment: just fyi, using `remote` is nothing more different than `Transfer data from main process to render process`. If you noticed some perf slowness without remote when ipc between processes, using remote will only makes slower (cause it's sync ipc underlying)